# HeadFirstJava Guessing Game

Tags: java

I have some experience with C and PHP but never really touched OOP. Started Headfirst Java book and got confused about this guessing game program. I don't understand just the first part of the program. what is going in GuessGame class in the beginning?

```
public class GuessGame{
    Player p1;   
    Player p2;
    Player p3;

    public void startGame() {
        p1=new Player();
        p2=new Player();
        p3=new Player();

        int guessp1=0;
        int guessp2=0;
        int guessp3=0;

        boolean p1isRight=false;
        boolean p2isRight=false;
        boolean p3isRight=false;

        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.Random() * 10);
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 9...");

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Number to guess is " + targetNumber);

            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();

            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.printn("Player one guessed " + guessp1);

            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.printn("Player two guessed " + guessp2);

            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.printn("Player three guessed " + guessp3);

            if(guessp1==targetNumber)
                p1isRight=true;

            if(guessp2==targetNumber)
                p2isRight=true;

            if(guessp3==targetNumber)
                p3isRight=true;

            if(p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println("We have a winner!");
                System.out.println("Player one got it right? " +p1isRight);
                System.out.println("Player two got it right? " +p2isRight);
                System.out.println("Player three got it right? " +p3isRight);
                System.out.println("Game's up.");
                break;
            }else 
                System.out.println("Players will have to try again.");
         }
     }
 }

     public class Player {
         int number = 0;
         public void guess() {
             number = (int) (Math.random()*10);
             System.out.println("I'm guessing " +number);
         }
     }

     public class GameLauncher {
         public static void main (String[] args) {
             GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
             game.startGame();
         }
     }
```

So this is what I don't understand :  I get that `p1= new Player();` means creating p1 object from class player but what does `Player p1` mean ? Is it a declaration of `p1` variable of type `Player`?

Comment: You need to have a class to define methods and fields in for Java. Even the main method must be in a class.

Comment: yes it is just a declaration @Misho Metreveli

Comment: `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are [member variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) of the class `GuessGame`.

Answer (score 0):

> what means "Player p1" ?

Yes, it is the declaration of the instance variable `p1` of type `Player`. Moreover, p1 has class scope, instead of method scope, so it can be read / written from any method of `GuessGame` (i.e. if it was declared inside `startGame()` it would have been available only in that method).
Again, it has package scope, meaning any other class in the same package as `GuessGame` can read its value through an instance of `GuessGame` (although there's no package declaration in the code you posted).

But, if you come from C (and not C++) I suggest you to do a little research about OOP concepts such as encapsulation, inheritance, etc just to get a rough idea.

Comment: member variable = instance variable? I just didn't get how the writer declared a variable of a new type without telling the program about this new type.

Comment: Well, that could be because it is an example. Yes, instance variable is more precise. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) there are *class variables* and *instance variables*, and both are class members. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @MishoMetreveli oh, but the author does tell the program about this Player type, in the very own snippet you posted you can see the following at the end:    public class Player {...} Although in real java you can't have more than one public class in a single file, you could get away declaring this Player class in a separate file and then using import statements on the GuessGame class or you could simple declare class Player{} without the public  modifier in the same file as GuessGame

Comment: @lucas.prestes Nice catch! I didn't carefully look at the posted code. Misho, differently from C (and C++ IIRC), in Java there's no need to declare the types before using them, so it is perfectly fine that `Person` comes after `GuessGame` (although, as lucas pointed out, there can be only one public class per file, so it could work if the other two class declarations had their `public` modifier removed).